# Dynamically change background of a div in css

Tags: css, background

This is an example of code in CSS:

```
  block {
        margin-left: 1in;
        margin-top; 1in;
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url('../images/myimage.png');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

Now I am using this CSS file on more than one HTML page and there need to be able to change this image per page. Maybe through HTML?

```
<block><somehowchangeimagehere></somehowchangeimagehere></block>
```

? Please, only HTML & CSS.

Comment: Do you want the same image on every page, or a different image on each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this is to put a class on the BODY tag for each page, then make different subclasses:

```
<body class="pageOne">
```

CSS:

```
.pageOne block {
    background-image: url('../images/myimageOne.png');
}

.pageTwo block {
    background-image: url('../images/myimageTwo.png');
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that once BLOCK is defined, you only need to sub-class the differences, not the whole block, as in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The image URL is relative to the CSS page URL, not the HTML page URL. It should just work.

Comment: The image obviously works but you don't understand what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to change the myimage.png per page. How would I achieve this?

Comment: @Ridz: Use custom CSS on each page?

Comment: @Ridz: If you want the image to be different on each page, then you can omit the image from the external CSS file and instead include `<style>block{background-image:url('custom image.png');}</style>` on your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert something like this in your html after you include the stylesheet you can override the stylesheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
    block {
        background-image('some_image_thats_specific_to_the_page');
    }
</style>
```